# What are some of the best quantitative finance websites?

Tags: quantitative, learning, resource

Not looking to start a debate. Just want to learn more about the field and am looking for some websites with high quality, informative content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's too broad and opinion-based. The moderators have previously closed threads asking what's the best quantitative finance conferences - a considerably more specific question, so a fortiori, this question would be too broad if our moderators are fair.

Comment: but the question was helpful all the same ;) Perhaps if he chaged the title to "Quality websites dealing with quant finance" or just "Websites providing discussion and information on quant finance". I don't think it should be close just renamed.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is spam, just like it was [spam on NP](http://www.nuclearphynance.com/Show%20Post.aspx?PostIDKey=170990).

Comment: I find that this question should be opened and protected

Answer (score 4):

It depends the kind of information you look for.

**Questions and answer.**
This web site is really the best I know on quant finance. You can browse "tags" and go the the associated wiki pages to have summarized information.

- Wilmott Forum is not that bad;
- [Nuclear Phynance](http://www.nuclearphynance.com) is good too.

**Generic knowledge.**
It depends on what area on finance you are interested in.
Frankly I would recommend the **web sites of market authorities**, they often publish reports and *policy papers*. The website of the [Louis Bachelier Institute](http://www.louisbachelier.org/) (in French only) is nice too, and more systematically quant oriented.

But the best is to **read books**, for instance a mix of very classical ones and more recent ones.

Answer (score 2):

Besides this site which in my opinion has a huge adventage on how the questions and answers are presented, two major players come to mind.

- [The Wilmott Forum](http://www.wilmott.com/index.cfm?NoCookies=Yes&forumid=1)
- [And the QuantNet-Community](https://www.quantnet.com/)

I would say QuantNet is more on the educational and job-search side. You will find a lot of resources with respect to interview question and acedemic master programms.

Wilmott is has lots of everything. You could check out some of the [blogs here](http://www.wilmott.com/blogs.cfm) for example. Also to my knowledge many quants have their personal websites where they share their research and perspektives.

Answer (score 2):

Agree, a little broad topic. There are sites that use quant to pick stocks. fotatah.com is an example of site.

It all depends on your goals (academic, trading,  etc.)

Comment: could you name some more ? - for both academia and trading :)